# What is the difference between the shear modulus G and the shear relaxation modulus G(t)?

Tags: classical-mechanics, elasticity

The sear modulus has no time dependence while the shear relaxation modulus has a time dependence. Is there a way to obtain G from G(t)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Rubinstein (Polymer Physics ISBN 9780198520597 section 7.6.1) the shear modulus is  $G=\lim_{t\to \infty} G(t)$ which takes some non-zero value for solids.